# Быстрый thread pool для бенчмарков

Tags: java, производительность, concurrency

Мне необходимо в бенчмарке выполнять некоторые операции в другом потоке, для того что бы их не создавать каждый раз, я хочу иметь трэд пул и в нем выполнять эти операции.

Достаточно ли быстрый джавовый ExecutorService или стоит написать свой ?

Comment: Что такое быстрый тред пул? Постарайтесь ответить на этот вопрос, чтобы понять, что исходный вопрос просто не имеет смысла.

Comment: @etki  быстрый трэд пул - это трэд пулл, который выполняет то что мне нужно: я хочу вызывать у него submit, а он будет брать свободный поток и в нем запускать мой runnable . Это не очевидно для вас?

Comment: @voipp вы сейчас описали **любой** тред пул

Comment: @etki поясню : мне нужно что бы он делал только это и не больше, никакой больше функциональности .

Comment: @voipp если вы боитесь, что он как-то замедлит вам Runnable, то без инструментации он этого сделать не сможет. Единственный вопрос производительности, который реально может встать - это вопрос времени от submit до начала выполнения Runnable, но он не будет иметь какого-либо влияния в реальном бенчмарке, потому что реальный бенчмарк всегда будет на порядки дольше этого отрезка времени.

Comment: @etki бенчмарки бывают разные, есть те, где происходит мало операций

Comment: Это как раз не бенчмарки, а имитация, потому что подвержены эффектам инициализации и спорадических замедлений.

Comment: @etki для этого бенчмарк сначала прогревается , и гоняется долго, что бы случайные колебания значений не портили статистику

Comment: я ж и говорю, в сравнении со временем выполнения бенчмарка временем от submit до запуска runnable можно пренебречь

Comment: @etki вы проверяли это?) или просто считаете

Answer (score 0):

Судя по тому что происходит внутри кода `ThreadPoolExecutor`, вам он не подходит. Потому что внутри него создается поток для новой задачи, этого можно избежать, создав такой поток с помощью пустой задачи заранее, но все же много логики остается. Думаю что-то своё, что будет в цикле ожидать появления чего либо в `AtomicReference` или `ConcurrentQueue` будет быстрее.

Это с одной стороны. С другой стороны, не забывайте, что в любом случае есть такая штука как операционная система и время на переключения контекста при смене потока. Вам все равно не получится избежать некоторых задержек. (если вы когда нибудь писали тесты скажем на си, то там всегда результаты отличались на 10-20, порой даже на 100мс - вот вам и система)

То есть у вас уже есть ограничения на длительность теста, чтобы можно было как-то свести работу системы до "в пределе погрешности".

В третьих Java машина. Она постоянно оптимизирует код, ориентироваться на цифры полученые просто самописными тестами с System.currentTimeMillis очень сложно. Это уже тема отдельного вопроса, есть определенные бенчмарки, есть списки правил, что-то конкретное подсказать сложно, не было у меня необходимости еще получать точные цифры.

В четвертых, это что такой за бенчмарк с отдельными потоками? Конечно может быть у вас там "всё схвачено" и вы понимаете что делаете, но звучито это странно. По крайней мере в совокупности с заморочками насчет скорости тред пула.

В общем как вывод - тред пул далеко не самая большая проблема что у вас возникает. Используйте обычный ThreadPoolExecutor, если вдруг вам покажется, что он на что-то там влияет, ну напишите свою реализацию. Это по факту дело 10 минут.

Comment: переключение контекста потоков - это то, что мне стоит учитывать в бенчмарке, это нормально. Так же не стоит забывать про разогрев бенчмарка